# Magento 1.9.0.1 - Add custom phtml to header

Tags: magento

I'm trying to output a custom phtml file to the header of my Magento Website. The following are the changes I've made:
Is there any reason why this is not working for me? Nothing is being output

Local.xml

```
<reference name="head">
    <block type="core/text" name="wc-how-to" template="wc-how-to.phtml"/>   
    <!-- <block type="core/text" name="wc-how-to" template="wc-how-to.phtml" output="toHtml"/> -->

</reference>
```

wc-how-to.phtml

```
<div class="wc-how-to">
This is some test text
</div>
```

header.phtml

```
 echo $this->getChildHtml('wc-how-to');
```

Comment: I love people who vote-down my very clear question down for no apparent reason. Come here and I'll give you a kiss for being useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the **reference name** .It should be **header** and not **head**

```
<reference name="header">
    <block type="core/text" name="wc-how-to" template="wc-how-to.phtml"/>   
    <!-- <block type="core/text" name="wc-how-to" template="wc-how-to.phtml" output="toHtml"/> -->

</reference>
```

Comment: Also type="core/text" didn't work but "core/template" did
Thanks!

Comment: Missed that part.Glad to know that you found out!!